# Lock in multiprocessing package not working

Tags: python, locking, multiprocessing

The following code is very simple, only for testing purposes, but I am not getting the output as desired:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Lock

def printing(l,i):
    l.acquire()
    print i
    l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for i in range(10):
        Process(target=printing,args=(lock,i)).start()
```

The output is:

```
0
1
2
3
5
6
4
7
8
9
```

Locks are supposed to suspend the other processes from executing. Why isn't it happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What output did you expect?  The output looks fine to me:  a permutation of `range(10)`.  The **order** in which the Processes happen to execute may vary from run to run.  That's expected.

I suspect you misunderstand what a lock does.  When you acquire a lock, then every other process also trying to acquire the same lock blocks until the lock is released.  That's all.  In your test run, process 0 happened to acquire the lock first.  Any other processes also trying to acquire the lock are blocked until process 0 releases the lock.  Process 0 prints `0` and then releases the lock.  Then it so happened that process 1 acquired the lock.  Etc.

Comment out your `l.release()`, and you'll see that your program never finishes:  the first process that happens to acquire the lock then prints its integer, and all other processes are forever blocked waiting to acquire the lock.

Comment: I now understand what the lock does. Thank You for that.

So how do we control the order of the Processes?

Comment: You should probably open a new question for that.  The **point** of multiprocessing is to execute processes in parallel, not one at a time.  If you want to do one at a time, fine, start one process and wait for it to finish, then start another process - etc.